# DOM Elements Styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a web application using javascript and CSS and I am using Firebase Firestore for my database. I am still relatively new in my web development journey and require any assistance/guidance that can be given. In order to display my values I was using template strings using innerHTML. Due to some limitation I encountered by doing this, I decided to use DOM elements and just use create and appendChild etc to render my html.

1. Currently, I have all of the functionality I require working except for 1 thing. I decided to focus on functionality first and then figured I would style the page later. Now, I am not sure if I am doing this correctly or if there is an easier way to do this but, I have a few DOM elements created and I just had them created as "divs", then I had them as "spans", then I played around with a mixture in order to get what I believe is a desirable layout. When I use span everything is just stuck together so I abandoned that and just placed everything as "p" so that they will be on a new line when displayed. I also started to play around with my CSS and change margins and left/right alignments because everything just wasn't lining up correctly. This has been a real marathon.

Am I doing this correctly?

```
let model = document.createElement('p');
let brand = document.createElement('p');
let manufacturer = document.createElement('p');
let colour = document.createElement('p');
let quantity = document.createElement('p');
let size = document.createElement('p');
let description = document.createElement('p');

model.textContent = product.model;
model.classList.add("model");
brand.textContent = product.brand;
brand.classList.add("brand");
manufacturer.textContent = product.manufacturer;
manufacturer.classList.add("manufacturer");
colour.textContent = product.colour;
colour.classList.add("colour");
quantity.textContent = product.quantity;
quantity.classList.add("quantity");
size.textContent = product.size;
size.classList.add("size");
description.textContent = product.description;
description.classList.add("description");
```

Below is what I have. Initially I wanted to have some of them on the left and some on the right almost as with a table but without using a table but that was challenging. I was able to do this when I was using the template string and just manually doing the html with the tags.

Lysol

Reckitt Benckiser

Yellow

1

LYSOL Disinfecting Wipes are the convenient way to clean and disinfect your household surfaces.

---

2. ANOTHER question I have is what is the best way to add text in front of these? Like the below example

**Brand:** Lysol

**Manufacturer:** Reckitt Benckiser

**Color:** Yellow

Thanks in advance for any assistance/guidance you can give me.

```js
 for(let prod of products){
           console.log("Doc ID",doc.id);

        const li1 = `
            <p><div>${prod.name} <div class="right"><font class=pink-text>Location:</font> $${prod.location}  <button data-remove-button-id="${doc.id}" class="btn-remove">Delete</button></div></div></p>
        `;
        html += li1;

        } //end for loop




        const li2 = `
            <br />
            <button class="btn blue darken-2 z-depth-0 right modal-trigger" data-target="modal-prodedit">Add/Edit Attributes</button><br />
            </div>
            </li>
        `;
        html += li2;                    

        productList.innerHTML = html;


        const removeBtn = document.querySelector(`[data-remove-button-id="${doc.id}"]`);
        console.log("removeBTN",removeBtn);
        removeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
            console.log(`deleted row ${e.target.dataset.removeButtonId}`);
          });
```

Comment: What exactly where the limitations of the template string? Because using one for this will be a lot easier. Also, can you add your actual resulting HTML to the question, together with your CSS? Use the `<>` button in the editor.

Comment: Here's a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yqujx5ds/

Comment: @ChrisG The limitation I am referring to was easily assigning unique values to buttons generated inside a for loop which I could then use to edit or add values to a specific item. As for the resulting HTML, it is pretty much what I have there....very basic....just the values listed on a new line with a space between them. My CSS for the most part is just me messing around with the margins etc because I have icons that weren't lining up properly. I will try to grab that and post here.

Comment: That limitation sounds definitely solvable. Can you add the for loop you've tried to your question? And also limit your question to a clear problem that isn't solved by simply learning more about the languages using existing resources?

Comment: I've added an edit button to my fiddle that demonstrates how to access the correct product data object.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks. The issue with the for loop and the template string was that how i did it (shown in the example) was that it would only work for the last button  in the list and I know it is because it was destroying the innerHTML every time I use html = x. Because of how my firestore database it i needed it to pull values from one area of the database and then all of the values under that so it would loop through to find all of those values and display them with a unique edit button for each.

Comment: Your example though looks as though it may have worked for my scenario and using querySelectorAll()

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG got this working